# MySQL date format in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

How can i show this as a DAY rather than full date

```
echo "<td align='left' valign='middle' bgcolor='" . $color . "'><font size='" . $fontsize . "'>" . $row['date'] . "</td>";
```

i already have

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
```

i have a similar question already asked but mistakenly put it as MYSQLi but i need MYSQL PHP support on this

the date and time is correctly set for the timezone but on viewing the PHP i want to view it as a Day

Answer (score 2):

Use the date() function in PHP to change the date format...

```
date('l',strtotime($row['date']));
```

So your code changes to this...

```
echo "<td align='left' valign='middle' bgcolor='" . $color . "'><font size='" . $fontsize . "'>" . date('l',strtotime($row['date'])) . "</td>";
```

**Info** on `date()`

Date can display in many different ways...

```
date('Y-m-d');  //2013-06-17 format
date('z'); //day of the year
date('l'); //textual day of week
```

See here for details...

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

**UPDATE**

You are having trouble with the format, so you can fix it like this...

```
$date = explode(" ",$row['date']);
$date2 = explode("/",$date[0]);
$displayDay = date('l',strtotime($date2[2]."-".$date2[1]."-".$date2[0]));
```

Then just echo that line with

```
echo "<td align='left' valign='middle' bgcolor='" . $color . "'><font size='" . $fontsize . "'>" . $displayDay  . "</td>";
```

Comment: i tried the above and i get **17/06/2013 0:32:55** am showing as **THURSDAY** which is wrong because it should show as **MONDAY**

Comment: Well thats probably the strtotime function screwing up your date, you may have to filter it twice...what is the exact format of your date....when echoed in PHP?

Comment: yes when i **echo "<td align='left' valign='middle' bgcolor='" . $color . "'><font size='" . $fontsize . "'>" . date('l',strtotime($row['date'])) . "</td>";**  it shows as THURSDAY for today

Answer (score 0):

what is your current output and how do you want it to be? probably something like `date('d m Y', $row['date'])`but that depends heavily on the column type of your date col.

Comment: i already have that set on INSERT INTO **date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
$date = date('d/m/Y G:i:s a', time());** so it would output for me **17/06/2013 0:32:55 am**

Answer (score 0):

assumed `17/06/2013 0:32:55 am` is your output on `$row[date]`:

something like this:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y G:i:s', $row[date]);

echo date('D', $date->getTimestamp());
```

I didn't check for the format operators, but that's easy to look up